# How to transform Typescript interface with multiple call signatures?

Tags: typescript

Spent a lot of time, but with no luck. I need to transform TS interface, containing call signatures.
from this

```
interface Emits {
  (event: "update:modelValue", inputValue: any): void;
  (event: "search", inputValue: string): void;
  (event: "close"): void;
}
```

to this

```
interface Emits = {
  "onUpdate:modelValue": (inputValue: any) =>  void;
  "onSearch": (inputValue: string) =>  void;
  "onClose": () => void;
}
```

My implementation works only for one function.
looks like this

```
  type EmitsToProps<T> = T extends
    {
      (event: infer FirstArgument, value?: infer SecondArgument): any
    } ? {
    [K in string & `on${Capitalize<string & FirstArgument>}`]?: K extends `on${infer C}` ? SecondArgument extends null ? (...args: any[]) => any : (args?: SecondArgument extends (args?: infer P) => any ? P : never) => any : never;
} : {};
```

Comment: [Related Github Issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29732)

Comment: Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't let you programmatically access multiple call signatures, as mentioned in the linked issue above.  See the answers to the linked questions for possible approaches; it would be better to start with your props and generate emits, but if you can't do that, you might be able to proceed with some limited fixed number of overloads as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1EkXw).  It's not great, though.